# How to implement field-based access control in spring data rest?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

How can I implement field-based access control in spring data rest? The following example will decribe in more detail what I am trying to do.

I have for example a UserResource which can create and update users. Now I want my Users to be able to create update users. This works fine so far. But now I have some fields (e.g. the users roles) which I only want user with the role admin to be able to create/change.

How can I implement this. If possible I would prefer a generic way.